# Google OR Tools - The Idea to Sort IntVar

Tags: or-tools

An example:

```
x1 = model.NewIntVar(0, 100, '')
x2 = model.NewIntVar(0, 100, '')
x3 = model.NewIntVar(0, 100, '')
x4 = model.NewIntVar(0, 100, '')
```

Like a warehouse layout optimization project, now I want the second largest IntVar and the third largest IntVar to have a constraint like as follow:

```
model.Add(x[the second largest IntVar's index] - x[the third largest IntVar's index] >= 10)
```

I know google offers the function of model.AddMaxEquality, but it doesn't seem to work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can adapt the [ranking sample](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/main/ortools/sat/docs/scheduling.md#ranking-tasks-in-a-disjunctive-resource-with-a-circuit-constraint) by getting rid of the interval variables, and just add precedences between the integer variables.

One thing is not clear in your description, you want the rank of each variable in the sorted by value array, or you want the index of the sorted values, independently of which variable takes this value?

Comment: It is so nice of you to reply me. I want the IntVars sorted by value, and to get the index of the desired IntVar. Like I mentioned above, the constraint " >= 10" is just an assumption. In real case, I want to use the index of desired IntVar to look up some value. Like, x2 would be the second largest IntVar and x3 would be the third, and I don't want these two points to be too close while satisfying the required width of rack1 or rack2. I will look into what you said and thank you.

Comment: Wrong link. I fixed it.